# Swift: Functions called in the wrong order?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I've been working on a Weather App with the following brief Data Model

```
class CurrentWeather
{
    private var _cityName: String!
    private var _date: String!
    private var _weatherType: String!
    private var _currentTemp: Double!

    var cityName: String
    {
        if _cityName == nil
        {
            _cityName = ""
        }
        return _cityName
    }

    // Same idea for getters var date, var weatherType and
    //  var currentTemp (returns 0.0 if it is nil)
    // Not showing that here 

    func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete)
    {
    // Function which computes values though a url and stores in instance variables
    // Not showing the entire actual function here
                self._cityName = name.capitalized. // value computed earlier
                print(self._cityName)
                self._weatherType = main.capitalized // value computed earlier
                print(self._weatherType)


                self._currentTemp = currentTemp - 273.15 // value computed earlier
                print(self._currentTemp)

                completed()

     }

}
```

where the type `DownloadComplete` is a type alias to `()->()`

In the main ViewController.swift, I have created an object and called this function (with trailing closure syntax)

```
var currentWeather: CurrentWeather!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentWeather = CurrentWeather()
    currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails {
         self.updateMainUI() // I have created this function
    }
}
func updateMainUI()
{
    dateLabel.text = currentWeather.date
    currentTempLabel.text = String(currentWeather.currentTemp)
    locationLabel.text = currentWeather.cityName
    currentWeatherTypeLabel.text = currentWeather.weatherType
    currentWeatherImage.image = UIImage(named: currentWeather.weatherType)

    print("Tested: \(currentWeather.currentTemp)")
    print("Tested: \(currentWeather.cityName)")
    print("Tested: \(currentWeather.weatherType)")
}
```

**So the Expected output:**

Logically,

1. I have created a `CurrentWeather` object
2. Called the `downloadWeatherDetails` function which should load the different computed values in the private vars.
3. Call the user defined `updateMainUI` function which displays the different values on my app's UI

So the output should be like

```
Birim. //cityname

Clear. //weatherType

29.134 //currentTemp

Tested: 29.134

Tested: Birim

Tested: Clear
```

**But the output which I get is**

```
Tested: 0.0

Tested:             (indicating "")

Tested:             (indicating "")

Birim

Clear

29.134
```

So, basically the functions `downloadWeatherDetails` and `updateMainUI` are called in the wrong order? Why is this so? Is this somehow related to asynchronous execution of functions?

I have tried not using the trailing closure, but it still doesn't work.

I also tried leaving the closure empty and calling `updateMainUI` after `downloadWeatherDetails` call like this

```
currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails {

}
self.updateMainUI()
```

But this too doesn't work. Any ideas of why the functions are called in the wrong order?

**UPDATE:**

the underscore variables are private vars while the non-underscore variables are the getters like

```
    var cityName: String
    {
        if _cityName == nil
        {
            _cityName = ""
        }
       return _cityName
    } 

     // Same idea for getters var date, var weatherType and
     //  var currentTemp (returns 0.0 if it is nil)
     // Not showing that here
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Project files are here(in case one may want to refer): https://github.com/danny311296/Weather-App

Comment: You need to show the rest of the code in your `downloadWeatherDetails` method.  You're probably calling your completion handler in the wrong place.

Comment: I've just attached the GitHub link to the project. That exact file can be found here https://github.com/danny311296/Weather-App/blob/master/Weather%20Forcast/CurrentWeather.swift

Comment: You need to call your completion handler inside the alamofire completion handler

Comment: Thanks a lot, dan! It's working now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call your 'completed()' function within the Alamofire request callback. Since the request function is asynchronous it does not wait for it to finish before executing completed().

```
Alamofire.request(CURRENT_WEATHER_URL).responseJSON { response in

    // handle response...

    // when done call completed
    completed()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that your "updateMainUI" method is being called before the completion of download process. Although you have implemented the Completion Listener, this should be working but I don't what's wrong with that. Try to use some other methods like delegation or notification to observe the downloading processes.

Check this link to see other method to observe completion:

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-three-ways-to-pass-data-from-model-to-controller-b47cc72a4336

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated reply. I will look into that.